# WebUI for Distributed Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

Earlier I was using Spark and was very familiar with Spark WebUI (localhost:8080). I was able to check if a worker has connected to the master, how many workers are connected? Amount of RAM utilized in each worker and so on.

Tensorflow uses gRPC for distributed computing. RAM and GPU Memory are vital for distributed computing. **Is there any utility which acts like a Spark WebUI for Distributed Tensorflow, assuming first parameter server / task id as master and workers as slave?**

**Note**: Using a Summary writer with the help of a single worker and loading the logs in tensorboard is different from what I want to achieve.